# Saving Array, from blade to controller Laravel

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.8

I want to save all of these data which is might be an array, into my answer table. I have tried so many ways but cant seem to find a correct solution.. can someone helped me thank you. I dont how to store the data from the answer(create.blade.php) into a database which is on the store function in the AnswerController as I dont didn't understand how to use that $key=> $value stuff. Im still learning as I really put my heart on Laravel. Can someone who is Laravel's expertise help me or guide me? Thankyou so much..

**Question Model**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    public function feedback()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Feedback','feedback_id');
    }

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }

}
```

Answer Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['question_id', 'feedback_type', 'answer'];

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Answer','question_id');
    }

   /* public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Answer','user_id');
    } */
}
```

**Answer** (create.blade.php)

```html
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" method="post" action="{{action('AnswerController@store')}}">
    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-53">
        Survey Page
    </span>

    @csrf,
    @foreach ($questions as $question)
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="question[]" value="{{$question->id}}">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="txt1">
                Soalan : {{$question->question_desc}}
            </div>
        </div>

        @if($question->question_type === 'rating')
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <span class="txt1">
                    Jawapan :
                    <span class="rating">
                        <input id="rating5[{{$question->id}}]" type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]"
                               value="5">
                        <label for="rating5[{{$question->id}}]">5</label>
                        <input id="rating4[{{$question->id}}]" type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]"
                               value="4">
                        <label for="rating4[{{$question->id}}]">4</label>
                        <input id="rating3[{{$question->id}}]" type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]"
                               value="3">
                        <label for="rating3[{{$question->id}}]">3</label>
                        <input id="rating2[{{$question->id}}]" type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]"
                               value="2">
                        <label for="rating2[{{$question->id}}]">2</label>
                        <input id="rating1[{{$question->id}}]" type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]"
                               value="1">
                        <label for="rating1[{{$question->id}}]">1</label>
                    </span>
                 </span>
            </div>
        @elseif($question->question_type === 'option')
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                Jawapan :
                <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]" value="yes">
                <label>YES</label>
                <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]" value="no">
                <label>NO</label>
            </div>
        @elseif($question->question_type === 'text')
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <span class="txt1">
                    Jawapan :
                    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" id="answer" rows="3" name="answer[{{$question->id}}]"></textarea>
                 </span>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
        <button class="login100-form-btn">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AnswerController**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Feedback;
use App\Answer;
use App\Question;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class AnswerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $questions = Question::all();
        return view('Answer.index',compact('questions'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $questions = Question::all();
        return view('Answer.create',compact('questions'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       foreach ($request->question as $key => $value){
           $answer = new Answer();
           $answer -> question_id = $value;
           $answer -> answer = $request->input('answer');
           $answer -> save();
       }

        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

**Route**

```php
<?php

Route::resource('feedbacks','FeedbackController');
Route::resource('questions','QuestionController');
Route::resource('answers','AnswerController');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: With you saying you don't understand the "`$key => $value` stuff" are you saying you're not use to using `foreach` loops or is it something else?

Comment: I know how to use foreach in order to display the data, but in order to set a key in it, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is in your controller when you get the answer from request:

```
$answer -> answer = $request->input('answer');
```

The request contains an array of answers by `question_id` as the key. So you can get the related answer by:

```
$answer -> answer = $request->input('answer.'.$value);
```

**The key point is Laravel uses dot notation for getting array posts.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! May i know in the $value attribute, what data does it store it in? Is it a question id?

Comment: Your welcome. I am not sure ```$request->question``` would give you the array of questions has sent. But using ```$questions = Input::get('question');``` works fine. It would give the array you can iterate by just like you want.